# Add selected options value into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 multiple select boxes where I select some of the options and add it to the other select box. When i click on save, the selected option values should be stored into one array and passed to the home controller. when i put alert i get the proper data but I get the below error in firebug console which i'm not able to solve it.Plse help me in this regard. here is the error and code.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= PairedSelectBox.options.length; i++) {
    selectedClientChips.push(PairedSelectBox.options[i].value);
    alert("selectedClientChips == " + selectedClientChips);
}
```

I get the error in console like this

```
TypeError: PairedSelectBox.options[i] is undefined
selectedClientChips.push(PairedSelectBox.options[i].value);
```

This is the html code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label style="font-size: medium;">Client Chip details</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Search</label>
            <input type="text" id="searchId">
            <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="getClientChipDetails();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label style="font-size: small;">Client-Chip data</label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <label style="font-size: small">Selected Client-Chip data</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="MasterSelectBox" name="MasterSelectBox" size="10" multiple="multiple"></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="btnAdd">> </button>
            <br>
            <button id="btnRemove">< </button>
        </td>

        <td>
            <select id="PairedSelectBox" name="PairedSelectBox" size="10" multiple="multiple">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

This is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#MasterSelectBox').pairMaster();
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        $('#MasterSelectBox').addSelected('#PairedSelectBox');
    });
    $('#btnRemove').click(function () {
        $('#PairedSelectBox').removeSelected('#MasterSelectBox');
    });
});
```

Comment: `PairedSelectBox.options[i].value` does not exists. That's the reason you got the undefined message. Did you listed the whole object to see the entire object structure? Can you show the object itself?

Comment: I get the idea i'm missing some code. where do you define `var PairedSelectBox` ?

Comment: PairedSelectBox is an id of the select option.        <td>
            <select id="PairedSelectBox" name="PairedSelectBox" size="10" multiple="multiple">
            </select>
        </td>

Comment: Simo Endre, is does exist. In the alert i get the values

Comment: And how do you obtain the values from the select option?

Comment: I'm getting the values from db and displaying it in one select box(masterSelectBox), and from then i select 2-3 data and move them to the other select box(PairedSelectBox), and then when i click on save i need to send the data which is in pairedselectBox to controlled

Comment: @madhu that is where you write the html tag, yes. but that does not immediately make it accessible in javascript. unless you retreive the element by its id (with jquery, that works like this : `$('#PairedSelectBox')`)

Comment: I have showed something in this jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/f778yhxv/6/ pls have a look at my html. whatever i select in the masterbox should be moved to the pairedbox and when clicked on save i need the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/f778yhxv/8/). I modify your code.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Master select box</td><td>Paired select box</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="MasterSelectBox" name="MasterSelectBox" size="10" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button id="btnAdd"> > </button><br>
            <button id="btnRemove"> < </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="PairedSelectBox" name="PairedSelectBox" size="10" multiple="multiple"></select>
        </td>        
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="save">Save</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
    $('#MasterSelectBox').pairMaster();
    $('#btnAdd').click(function(){
        $('#MasterSelectBox').addSelected('#PairedSelectBox');
    });
    $('#btnRemove').click(function(){
        $('#PairedSelectBox').removeSelected('#MasterSelectBox');
    });
    $( "#save" ).click( function( e ) {
        $( "#output" ).empty();
        $.each( $( "#PairedSelectBox" ).val(), function( i, v ) {
            $( "#output" ).append( $( "<span> " + v + " </span>" ) );
        } );
    } );
});
```

P.S. and use `rawgit.com` links to libraries, not `raw.githubusercontent.com` to attach scripts to `jsfiddle`.

Answer (score 0):

@madhu i had update your code on jsfiddle with following code...

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var data=[];
    //$('#MasterSelectBox').pairMaster();
    $('#btnAdd').click(function(){
        $("#MasterSelectBox option:selected").each(function () {  
    var selText = $(this).val();  
   data.push(selText);
});      

      $.each(data, function(val, text) {
                    $('#PairedSelectBox').append( $('<option>').text(text).attr('value',text));
                    }); 

    });
    $('#save_btn').click(function(){
        alert("your data is"+JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
```

check your jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

I got it... I had nott delcard the pairedSelectBox.
 var PairedSelectBox = document.getElementById("PairedSelectBox");
//   alert("PairedSelectBox==="+ PairedSelectBox);

```
 for (var i = 0; i<PairedSelectBox.options.length; i++) {
     selectedClientChips.push(PairedSelectBox.options[i].value);
     //alert("selectedClientChips == " + selectedClientChips); 
     }
 alert("selectedClientChips==="+selectedClientChips);
```